# What is the impact of changing rails secret_key_base on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

As far as I know, secret_key_base is only used for signing cookies and changing secret_key_base will cause existing cookies to become invalid. I need to change secret_key_base on production, having existing users logged out is acceptable behavior but I am concerned about possible other side effects. Will the old cookies simply be deleted/replaced when they next visit the website or will they hang around and cause issues? Are there any other changes that will occur other than users being logged out?

Answer (score 3):

> The application’s key_generator, and thus secret_key_base, are used by three core features within the Rails framework:
>
> 1 Deriving keys for encrypted cookies which are accessible via cookies.encrypted.
>
> 2 Deriving the key for HMAC signed cookies which are accessible via cookies.signed.
>
> 3 Deriving keys for all of the application’s named message_verifier instances.

you can read more at https://medium.com/@michaeljcoyne/understanding-the-secret-key-base-in-ruby-on-rails-ce2f6f9968a1

The impact of your application by changing the `secret_key_base` on prod will depend on how many cookies your application depends on.  I would say all your clients will have to regenerate their cookies 1 time after that it should be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The secret_key_base can be upgraded in a rotating way, with no impact to the users.
[I have found a tutorial on how to do this here.](https://blog.kmkonline.co.id/rotating-ruby-on-rails-secret-key-base-9a4dcdf0d817)

This seems to work, and following this tutorial, I was able to install an automated periodic renew of the secret_key_base, per scheduler, with configurable timespan. Only if users stay inactive for longer than that timespan (e.g. 3 months), their session will become invalid.

This applies to the standard rails functionality of protecting the session-cookie. If your application does other things with the secret_key_base, then you will have to process respective rotations there also.